# Exim4/Dovecot Error: User@domain.tld is undeliverable: Unrouteable address

Tags: exim

Seeking some assistance with the above error.

Just configured Exim4/Dovecot mail server on Debian 10 buster, but having issue receiving mail.  It worked for some time during POC inhouse and now it's  not working after moving server to cloud, getting a bounce back email with error 550: mail is undeliverable. Testing with exim -bt user@domain.tld fails with user@domain.tld is undeliverable.

I have searched for solutions forever and could not find any decent instructions on how to resolve this issue.  I would highly appreciate any assistance.  Not sure if it's the routing or the transport issue on Exim4 to Dovecot or it's some thing else altogether.

I can provide the config info if anyone need it.

Comment: What is in the logs?

Comment: There is nothing in the panic log but when I run the exim -bt user1, I get the following error: "MAIN PANIC DIE /var/mail/domain.tld is not a regular file (lsearch lookup)".  users maildir sit in a folder with the domain name under var/mail/domain.tld/user1

Comment: `Host domain.tld not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`  I realise you were probably not being literal,  you need to do these check now  because we cannot.

Comment: please post near exact content or the bouce message.

Comment: Thanks for the response, to my questions, I really do appreciate it.  I believe I have resolved the question.  The messages were not getting delivered because Exim4 could not route it to correct vitual user maildir. I believe that is because it does not know about the users add in the dovecot passwd file.  So I add another file in etc/mail/domain.tld and added the names of the maildir users in that list.  With the router/transport sections already added in exim4-conf.template it started to work with the "exim -bt user1".  Now I am able to send the email and it gets delivered.